# Get custom user fields in google OAuth

Tags: google-oauth, google-admin-sdk

I'm new with the API and I want to get a custom field ScreenConnect form my connection with the OAuth2. I created my project in console.developers.google.com and I have authorized the Admin SDK. In my scope I put `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly`.

But I can't get the variable back. If I try `https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/schemas` to retrieve all custom schemas (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-schemas). I have `the Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes`.  But `https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/userKey` work fine (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get). So the restriction isn't coming from the SDK. I think it's a url error, but I can't understand what's going on.

I solved the error the Insufficient Permission with the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.userschema` I still can't find out how to get the value of the variable

Comment: Hello @The33Coder, which value of which variable are you talking about? Would you mind providing more details about it? That would be of great help! Cheers!

Comment: In my users, I have [created personal variables](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6208725?hl=en). One of these variables, contains the name of the group with the permissions and I want to give to this person when he connects to ScreenConnect with the OAuth. In fact, I want to give individual privileges to every user who connects with OAuth. Admin, user, manager...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope you are using is not the correct one since it only grants `readonly` access. In order to have access to what you want to achieve, you should be using this:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user`;

Moreover, if you want to retrieve the value set for each custom schema for a user, you will have to make the below `GET` request, where `userKey` is the user's email address.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/userKey
```

In addition to this, you also have to set the `customFieldMask` parameter with the name of your **schema name/s** and the `projection` parameter to **custom**.

Therefore, for a particular user, your request will look something like this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/THE_EMAIL_OF_THE_USER?customFieldMask=NAME_OF_THE_SCHEMA&projection=custom&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] 

HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

#### Reference

- [Directory API Users:get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get);